# What exactly causes guild war defences to get updated?

Tags: epic-seven

Say a guild member edits their guild war defence team or makes changes to some of their defence heroes’s gear. This won’t automatically be reflected in the actual “snapshot” of their defence (the team that opponents will actually end up facing) from when guild war assignments were last updated.

So what causes these defences to get updated? Pressing “Assign to Building” (triggers guild chat notification) and then going back out of the menu? Adding someone, taking someone out or swapping someone for another guild member directly; does that someone have to be them? Pressing the “Save Team Info” button (also triggers guild chat notification); do I actually have to make a change to existing participants’s positions &/or the composition of who is participating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving guild war assignments (pressing the “Save Team Info” button) causes everyone’s defence teams to be updated; it causes a fresh “snapshot” of all guild war defences to be taken, which your opponent would then face. You don’t have to make any actual changes to participant composition or existing participants’s positions, as long as you trigger that save, from any fortress or the stronghold.

This means, all you have to do is go into any fortress or the stronghold, start assigning by pressing the assign button, and then you can immediately save everything by pressing the save button.

This can be tested by anyone who has permissions to edit a guild war composition (vice captains or guild masters), by editing their own defence team and then performing a variety of actions to see what causes their defence to update.

However, I am unsure if the following count as a “save” and cause a new snapshot to be taken:

- When a guild war’s “war phase” ends and the previous guild war composition is carried over to the next war’s “preparation phase”
- When a participant leaves or is kicked from the guild, causing them to be immediately removed from their tower/fortress/stronghold if it happened during a “preparation phase”, or if there’s still a war going on or if it’s the Saturday break, right when the next “preparation phase” starts.

If you know the answer to these specific cases (which I cannot easily test), please do leave a comment below.